# How to Detect Which Emoji is Pressed keyboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, emoji, textmeshpro

I want to use Emoji's in my game But currently unity is not Supporting all Emoji's.
So, I decided to Find out that which Emoji is pressed from keyboard, or I can get the Unicode of the Emoji's pressed by keyboard.
Is there any way to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use emojis (probably in `InputField`), you first have to download font that supports emojis. You can also get a binary or unicode representation of character. Unity doesn't catch emojis with `Input.GetKeyDown`, so I suppose you want to do it with `InputField`. This is how you can do it:

```cs
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField inputField;

    private void Start()
    {
        inputField.onValidateInput += OnValidateInput;
    }

    private char OnValidateInput(string text, int index, char c)
    {
        print(@$"
binary:  {Convert.ToString(c, 2)};
unicode:  {"\\u" + ((int)c).ToString("X4")};
");

        return c;
    }
}
```

We just serialize `TMP_InputField`, where we see what character was written in `OnValidateInput` event. I hope that helps you!

Comment: this is Not working properly not showing the Unicode of the Emoji when emoji is Entered.

Comment: It won't show you emoji's unicode if your font doesn't have this emoji. You have to use a font that contains desirable emoji.